# Is there a general procedure for retrofitting "smart key" cars with real keys?

Tags: ignition, key, smartkey

With all the cost, trouble, loss-of-use, and [inability to shut the vehicle off if electronics fail](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2013/feb/13/french-driver-200kmh-car-chase) associated with "smart" keys, if I ever get a car that needs one I think I'd want to adapt it to start and stop with an ordinary mechanical key or other mechanism. Is there any clean, established way to do this? The most obvious solution that comes to mind is permanently mounting the original smart key inside the dash and adding an after-market ignition key unit, but are there better ways to disable the system or issues with leaving the smart key in the vehicle full-time?

Comment: The article you linked to talks about a car that's been `adapted for disabled drivers` It looks like that's the system that failed. It doesn't say anything about not being able to turn off. Although it seems very likely that he would have tried. What happens when you turn the power button off with your foot on the accelerator?